# Saving from Rails app in MYSQL database with capital ID: Mysql2::Error: Field 'ID' doesn't have a default

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on the post route with the create action on a rails 4 app. The database is an MYSQL one from a former PHP APP. It uses capital "ID" fields for the "Journey" table. My controller action to create a new entry in the database, causes the following Error Message:

Error Message

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO
```

Active Record call:

```
Journey.new(:Name => "Testbeni", :ContactPerson => "Frank", :ContactEmail => "f@f.de", :People => "3" )
```

What can I do so that ActiveRecord will let me post Journeys to the table? Is there any workaround with the ID issue?

Comment: How did you create the table for `Journey`? Can you share the schema for the same.

Comment: wow, new user came here to update the question. Great work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.

But i think you atleast have to tell active record about the primary key

```
  self.primary_key = "ID"
```

this should go inside `Journey` model.

About this error, it looks like primary key is not an `auto_increment` key. Check it. If isn't then you have to pass `ID`  value explicitly , something like this

```
Journey.new(:ID => 1212,:Name => "Testbeni", :ContactPerson => "Frank", :ContactEmail => "f@f.de", :People => "3" )
```